# How to find the group associated with a given symmetry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, physics, mathematical-physics

I have been doing some research as a theoretical physicist and I came across a physical system where any even number of quantum deformations of space leave the system unchanged.Hence two deformations is physically the same as say ten maybe and any other even number so that changing it doesn't change the physical situation.Is there any lie group that can be used to encode this symmetry? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to derive a symmetry group, you'll need to be quite a bit more precise in your description. What is the "system"/"space" (as a mathematical object)? What are the "deformations" and how do they act on the "space"?

Comment: Okay.I envisioned replacing particles in space with waves moving on a closed path (eg an ellipse).If any two of these "ellipse wave" were separated by a fixed distance,I find out that a chain of an even number other elliptical wave paths could be created between the initial two and the result would be a certain particle interaction and also that it doesn't matter what the even number value is....the interaction would be unchanged as long as the distance between both initial "waves" is fixed...I hope I passed the point across

Answer (score 2):

From a [group-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) perspective it seems to me that you are asking about an abstract group $G$ having the property that the product of every even length sequence of nontrivial elements of $G$ is equal to the identity element of $G$. Any such group $G$ is isomorphic to the order 2 [cyclic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group).

Ordinarily one doesn't think of $G$ as a Lie group, although one could certainly represent $G$ inside some Lie groups. Many Lie groups contain elements of order $2$. For example, in the Lie group $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ you can take $M$ to be any diagonalizable matrix all of whose eigenvalues are either $+1$ or $-1$, with at least one $-1$ eigenvalue, in which case $M^2=I$, the identity matrix, but $M \ne I$. Letting $G = \{M,I\}$ you get a subgroup $G$ of $GL(n,\mathbb C)$ that is isomorphic to the order 2 cyclic group.

Comment: Thanks @Lee Mosher